# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto' Python Firebase

Tags: python, pycryptodome

I know there are similar questions asked but I have read them and couldn't solved my problem I'm trying to `import pyrebase`; however it gives me these error messages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "c:\Users\yaman\OneDrive\Masaüstü\BİYOLOJİK ŞİFRELEME\JustSth.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyrebase
  File "C:\Users\yaman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyrebase\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .pyrebase import initialize_app
  File "C:\Users\yaman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyrebase\pyrebase.py", line 23, in <module>
    from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'
```

I downloaded the  pycryptodome and it says `Requirement Satisfied` when I try to install it again? How can I solve this problem?

Thanks from now!

Comment: Do you have more than one python installed? Or perhaps using an IDE that has its own python? You may not be installing it in the right place.

Comment: No I have only one which is Python 3.9.0 for 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
from Crypto.PubliCKey import *
```

or:

```
from Crypto import *
```

Comment: If `Crypto` doesn't exist, none of these will work either.

Comment: tdelaney is right. It didn't work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).